# Moment of Inertia tensor confusion

Tags: rotational-dynamics, notation, moment-of-inertia

This is the moment of inertia tensor about the COM.
$$I_{ij}'=\sum_{k=1}^Nm_k\left[\vert\mathbf{r}'^{(k)}\vert^2\delta_{ij}-r_i'^{(k)}r_j'^{(k)}\right]\neq I_{ij}$$

I don't understand how to compute the last term $r_{i}r_{j}$

I understand that $i$ and $j$ refer to the indices of the $r$ vector, I know that the $r_{j}$ is the transpose of $r_{i}$ but I still don't understand what the final tensor represents. Is it somehow storing the all possible results of $r_{i}r_{j}$?

It's kind of a vague question, but could you explain what $r_{i}r_{j}$ means?

Comment: *I know that the $r_{j}$ is the transpose of $r_{i}$.* No. The former is the $j$th component and is the latter is the $i$th component. Index notation is about *components* of vectors and tensors. There are no row vectors and column vectors in index notation.

Answer (score 1):

$r_i r_j$ is the i-th component of r multiplied by the j-th component of r. For example, if i=1 and j =3 then $r_i r_j = r_1 r_3 = xz$

$I_{ij}$ is the ij-th component of the moment of inertia tensor. This tensor is defined through $J_i = I_{ij} \omega_{j}$, where $\textbf{J}$ is the total angular momentum and $\bf{ \omega }$ is the angular velocity. Also note that the einstein summation convention is being used on the RHS.

i.e. it is the tensor which relates the ith component of the angular momentum to the 3 components of the angular velocity. In order to fully determine $\textbf{J}$ you would have to carry out the integral in your original question for all possible combinations of i and j, and then determine $J_1, \ J_2 $ and $J_3$.

To be super explicit I'll give an example:

$J_1 = I_{1j}\omega_{j} = I_{11} \omega_1 + I_{12} \omega_2  + I_{13} \omega_3 $

for $I_{11}$ the $r_i r_j$ term in the integral would be equal to $x^2$, for $I_{12}$ it would be $xy$ and for $I_{13}$ it would be $xz$.