# Einstein Summation Convention Confusion

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation, linear-algebra

My textbook:
[image]

The second bit confuses me. I asked a question on this site yesterday ([Moment of Inertia tensor confusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/806782/moment-of-inertia-tensor-confusion)) which involved the moment of inertia tensor and the term $$r_{i}r_{j}$$

The responses said that this results in a scalar because the $i$ and $j$ are indexing a vector which is a scalar. This makes sense. The reason I asked the question is because my textbook treated it as a matrix. Furthermore, the bottom example $$A_{i}B_{j}$$is similarly expressed as a matrix when by the reasoning of the responses on my previous question, it should be a scalar.

So is this a scalar or a matrix, if so, why?

Comment: *The responses said that this results in a scalar because the i and j are indexing a vector which is a scalar.* The responses did **not** say that components of vectors are scalars, and they *aren’t*. You might have a misunderstanding that a scalar is “one number”, a vector is “three numbers”, and a tensor is “nine numbers”.  But physicists instead define scalars, vectors, and tensors by how they transform under rotations.

Comment: $A_iB_j$ is the $(i,j)^\text{th}$ component of a tensor of rank 2. These nine components can be written as a matrix if you want, but that isn’t going to work when you get to $A_iB_jC_k$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both are OK. That may just a different use of notations. You could view this as $A_iB_j=(AB^T)_{ij}$ and the $i,j$ are just  indecies of the matrix's rows and columns.

Maybe what confuse you is whether sometimes we can commute the quantities (since numbers can easily commute and matrices cannot be commute). It will be explictly when you consider a certain calculation whether it is about the components of a matrix or a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

In your moment of inertia question Einstein summation convention is *not* being used, so $r_i r_j$ is simply the product of the $i$th and the $j$th element of the vector $\mathbf r$, so it is the product of two scalars (in the mathematical sense) and is itself a scalar. If we wanted to multiply the $i$th component of $\mathbf r$ by itself we would write this as $r_i r_i$, or, more concisely, as $(r_i)^2$.

However, in the example above in this question Einstein summation convention *is* being used, although in a rather non-standard way. The intention is to write the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of the vectors $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$, which is a matrix. Your textbook writes this as $A_iB_j$. However, strictly speaking you must turn $\mathbf B$ into a covector first (so that it is written as a row of elements rather than a column of elements), so the tensor product of $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ should be written in Einstein notation as $A^iB_j$. In this expression $i$ and $j$ are both free indices and can vary independently of one another.

On the other hand, the inner product of $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ would be written as $A^iB_i$, where there is implicit summation over the repeated index $i$ which is now a non-free (or "bound") index. Note that this is a scalar in the sense that physicists use the term, since it is invariant under a change of co-ordinates.

Comment: *it is the product of two scalars* A component of a vector is not a scalar.

Comment: @Ghoster Not to a physicist, but it is to mathematician. I have edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: When I learned about vector spaces in a math-department course, a scalar was something that could multiply a vector. Components of vectors were never once called scalars in my course.

Comment: @Ghoster But the fact that scalar multiplication works component-wise is because each vector component is also a scalar i.e. comes from the same field as the scalars in scalar multiplication. You cannot have scalar multiplication if your "vector" is (red, green) for example. "A quantity described by multiple scalars, such as having both direction and magnitude, is called a vector" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)

Comment: OK, I concede on what you are saying as a matter of math. But this is a physics site and we should use physicists’ definitions.